# Cassandra - ERROR: Doesn't have write permissions for ./../data/data directory

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I just now installed Datastax Enterprise. I trying to run the commands. I am using OS X (Sierra).

```
cd dse/bin
./cassandra
```

After some process I am getting errors like this:

```
ERROR 02:29:11 Doesn't have write permissions for ./../data/data directory
ERROR 02:29:11 Insufficient permissions on directory ./../data/data
```

I saw one of the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047141/how-to-configure-access-permissions-for-cassandra-on-linux-ubuntu/33048712) and found thier suggestion that run below commands:

```
sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra/data
sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
```

Even now I am getting other issue:

```
chown: cassandra: illegal group name
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you install DSE? `/var/lib/cassandra/data` is typical path from an installation from packages under linux while `./../data/data/` seems to be a tarball installation (for defaults locations etc see https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/install/dseTarLoc.html).

Your data directory is configured inside `dse` - you need to check the permissions there or configure your data directory in cassandra.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

At least in some cases CASSANDRA_HOME is set in

> bin/cassandra.in.sh

I am not sure how Cassandra gets there without CASSANDRA_HOME being set but there is no question that it can get there because the first thing cassandra.in.sh does is check if CASSANDRA_HOME is not initialized here:

```
if [ "x$CASSANDRA_HOME" = "x" ]; then
#    CASSANDRA_HOME="`dirname "$0"`/.."
     CASSANDRA_HOME=/usr/local/c4/cassandra
fi
```

Because cassandra.in.sh lives in bin/cassandra.in.sh this thing

> "`dirname "$0"`/.."

forces data/data (which is important, as you will learn) to be considered in

> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/bin/../data/data

To find where you put bin/cassandra.in.sh do a

> sudo updatedb
>
> locate data/data

In my case this is where I put it:

> server@think:$ locate data/data
>
> /usr/local/c4/cassandra/data/data

You can see above in the code box my solution for now is to hard code the location. I am sure I will figure out how it all works in good time. Now for the second part of your question you need to learn how Ubuntu uses group names to get that part to work. You were on the right track with:

> sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra/data
>
> sudo chown -R cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog

But you have not created the group yet, I used these instructions successfully:

> https://www.admintome.com/blog/install-cassandra-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Finally, I can see from my notes I did spend a fair amount of time getting this to work correctly even if I don't understand every part of Cassandra yet. If you would like to dig in the to mysteries of CASSANDRA_HOME yourself, start with this:

sudo grep -R "CASSANDRA_HOME" /usr/